# Am I taxed on the capital passed to my personal account when closing the company in Estonia?

Tags: taxes, capital-gains-tax, private-company, estonia

I am a freelance software developer from France. I lead a few others which I hire as contractors to work for companies. I am thinking about opening a company in Estonia as it seems I would be less taxed according to [this French article](https://lateraltrust.com/articles/filiale-offshore-estonie-comment-payer-0-dimpots/) thanks to the e-resident program.

> Mr. Filippe is a software developer. He wishes to develop a business
> of purchase/resale of sound equipment.
>
> In 2020, he creates a company in Estonia and makes a profit of 100.000
> euros per year. In 2025, he decides to stop his activity and to sell
> his business in order to obtain capital and to start real estate
> investment.
>
> [image]
>
> By locating his company in Estonia, Mr. Filippe saves 250,000 euros in
> taxes. By investing these savings at 10% per year, he could get an
> additional return of 25,000 euros per year.

Indeed, [there are 0% tax on reinvested profits.](https://www.e-resident.gov.ee/taxes-in-estonia/) That looks appealing however when I will close the company, I don't know if I would get taxed on the capital we would have made from the contract earnings.

Answer (score 1):

### What capital?

You are comparing a company that buys and resells sound equipment with a single-person software house. One is a business that a third-party might be interested in buying. The other is you wrapped up inside a company structure which has no capital value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added the details but the capital will be mainly from the earnings we will make.

Comment: That’s not capital - that’s revenue

Comment: Sure, which goes to the capital at the end of the year if it's reinvested, isn' it ?

Comment: You're using capital in an accounting sense, not a tax sense. Tax on revenue and capital gain is usually different - both become capital of the company if retained.